# How can I connect my apostrophe-cms to my rackspace server mongodb

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a heroku app instance that needs to point to a mongodb on rackspace. I've tried to update the uri to reflect the uri of the rackspace mongodb, but doesn't seem to connect. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

my guess is the URI option has not been put in the right place.

```
modules: {
  'apostrophe-db': {
    uri: 'mongodb://et-cetera'
  }
}
```

Or, your server has a firewall that is restricting outgoing connections.

Or, your rackspace server has a firewall that is restricting incoming connections.